# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How long should test results be kept?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/how-long-should-test-results-be-kept)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to start Selenium with Firefox Portable?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6619/how-to-start-selenium-with-firefox-portable)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What are some good approaches to separating test data from test scripts?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6678/what-are-some-good-approaches-to-separating-test-data-from-test-scripts)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Any tricks to using Microsoft Word to build cross-referenceable requirements statements in test plan documentation?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6569/any-tricks-to-using-microsoft-word-to-build-cross-referencable-requirements-stat)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is branching tests the only option for system with multiple versions?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6641/is-branching-tests-the-only-option-for-system-with-multiple-versions)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Does Microsoft provide any automation tool to test REST APIs?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/does-microsoft-provide-any-automation-tool-to-test-rest-apis)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to handle a native OS (Ubuntu) file upload window in selenium webdriver with python?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-handle-a-native-os-ubuntu-file-upload-window-in-selenium-webdriver-with)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Building trust in automated front-end testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/building-trust-in-automated-front-end-testing)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to simulate Caps Lock keystrokes with Selenium WebDriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/how-to-simulate-caps-lock-keystrokes-with-selenium-webdriver)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How to test a new Wildcard SSL Certificate?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6634/how-to-test-a-new-wildcard-ssl-certificate)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed pretty quickly: there's a mirroring site www.sqaanswers.co.uk that's doing a better job of getting to the top positions in search engines than we are. Every question I researched, the sqaanswers site ranked higher than sqa.stackexchange.

This doesn't reflect the quality of the questions, obviously, but suggests that we might need to tweak our own settings and keywords for search optimization.

Comment: Hmm, that's good to know. It also look like they're in violation of our attribution guidelines. I'll add that site to our list of mirror sites to contact.